# How do you flush the Hard Drive in Shrink Ray Island?

Tags: poptropica

A walk through says to "flush the hard drive-literally". Then once in the washroom, it says to stand on top of the toilet bowl and "use the hard drive to flush it in". That is what I did, but it says: "this is not a good place to use a hard drive".

Supposedly after you flush it, you can hear Mr.Silva mumbling about the location of the hard drive. I need to flush it to complete the island.

Comment: Did it actually say to use it on the toilet, or did it say to flush the hard drive? There's more than one meaning for 'flush'.

Comment: A walk through says to "flush the hard drive-literally". Then once in the washroom, it says to stand on top of the toilet bowl and "use the hard drive to flush it in". Supposedly after you flush it, you can hear Mr.Silva mumbling about the location of the hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue too, then out of frustration and curiosity I turned the lights out and it worked, point being: turn the light out, it's right next to the air switch thing.